# Dois Ajax Form em uma só página com múltiplos itens

Tags: javascript, ajax

Consigo fazer uma requisição Ajax da seguinte forma:

HTML

```
<div class="resultado_debito<?php echo $i ?>">
  <span class="ruim"><br>Inadiplente</span><br>

  <form method="post" id="quitar_debito<?php echo $i ?>" novalidate="novalidate">

   <input type="hidden" name="pagamento" value="sim"  class="pagamento">
   <input type="hidden" name="i" value="<?php echo $i ?>"  class="i">   
   <input type="hidden" name="id_empresa_pagamento" value="<?php echo $row["id"]?>" class="id_empresa_pagamento">
   <input type="submit" value="Quitar">     
</form>
</div>
```

Js Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() {

        //Remove a palavra quitar_ e deixa somente "debitoX"
        const formID = $(this).attr('id').replace("quitar_", "");

        //Captura o elemento que sofreu o evento de "submit"
        const formDetails = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'enviar_pagamento.php',
            data: formDetails.serialize(),
            success: function (data) { 
                // Inserting html into the result div
                $('.resultado_'+formID).html(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, text, error){
                // Displaying if there are any errors
                $('.resultado_'+formID).html(error);           
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Minha dúvida seria como eu posso colocar mais um formulario na mesma página com requisição Ajax para outro arquivo.

Perceba que o ID do Form varia de acordo com o registro do banco (**$i**), pois o ajax é executado em todos os registros do banco.

Comment: Bom, você já está recebendo as requisições que qualquer form disparar... Com relação ao destino, cada form pode ter seu action em si mesmo, via HTML. Desta forma, esqueça o id. Retorne nessa função, o form que deu o submit. Desta forma, poderá editar a tag correta. Consegue entender ou precisa de ajuda?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, seria só colocar um action em cada form? Poderia me dar um exemplo?

Comment: Vou responder com uma sugestão

Answer (score 0):

> **Exemplo Sugestão:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        //Captura o elemento que sofreu o evento de "submit"
        const formDetails = $(this);
        var dataIdx = formDetails.getAttribute('data-idx');
        
        $.ajax({
            type: formDetails.getAttribute('method'),
            url: formDetails.getAttribute('action'),
            data: formDetails.serialize(),
            success: function (data) { 
                // Inserting html into the result div
                $('.resultado_debito'+dataIdx).html(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, text, error){
                // Displaying if there are any errors
                $('.resultado_debito'+dataIdx).html(error);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="resultado_debito<?php echo $i ?>">
  <span class="ruim"><br>Inadiplente</span><br>

  <form method="post" novalidate="novalidate" action="enviar_pagamento.php" method="post" data-idx="<?php echo $i ?>">

   <input type="hidden" name="pagamento" value="sim"  class="pagamento">
   <input type="hidden" name="i" value="<?php echo $i ?>"  class="i">   
   <input type="hidden" name="id_empresa_pagamento" value="<?php echo $row["id"]?>" class="id_empresa_pagamento">
   <input type="submit" value="Quitar">     
   <div class="resultado">
   </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Nesse exemplo, o '.resultado está dentro do form. Caso esteja fora, e precise pegar pelo **ID**, Sugiro que passe o id no form com um atributo tipo **data-resultId="1"** , e pegue o resultado com o getAttribute que usei de exemplo...

Comment: assim ele dá o refresh na página o resultado teria que ficar dentro da div id resultado_debito<?php echo $i ?>

Comment: Veja agora. o que acontece... (Editei acima)

Comment: está retornando agora um erro no console Uncaught TypeError: formDetails.getAttribute is not a function var dataIdx = formDetails.getAttribute('data-idx');

Comment: Dúvida: Qual o conteúdo de formDetails? E, tente ao invés de getattribute, nesse caso, troque para **.data('idx')**. Troque os outros getAttribute por .attr(''). Ponha dentro das aspas o atributo em questão